# Writing to a JSON file with Java doesn't work after export

Tags: java, json, eclipse

When I use my program within Eclipse everything works flawlessly, the JSON file is saved between launches. The problem occurs when i export the project to a Runnable Jar File, the saving of the JSON file no longer works, at all. I can still read from the file, but it doesn't save it.

Here is the "writing/saving" code I've written.

```
/*
 * Write to character JSON file
 */
public void saveCharacterInfo() {

    JSONObject obj = JSONUtils.getJSONObjectFromFile("/character.json");
    obj.put("day", c.getDay());
    obj.put("name", c.getCharName());
    obj.put("hp", c.getCharHp());
    obj.put("maxHp", c.getCharHpMax());
    obj.put("armor", c.getCharArmor());
    obj.put("speed", c.getCharSpeed());
    obj.put("strength", c.getCharStrength());
    obj.put("money", c.getCharMoney());
    obj.put("food", c.getCharFood());
    obj.put("maxFood", c.getCharMaxFood());
    obj.put("morale", c.getCharMorale());
    obj.put("bait", c.getCharBait());

    try {

        URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("/character.json");
        File file = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write(obj.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: wich is the value of resourceUri.toUri ?

Comment: Don't catch exceptions without logging the error .

Comment: What is `JSONObject`?

Comment: @Tymomendog Then since it's not executing inside a project anymore there's no bin folder thus it can't create the file. Try creating the folder if it doesn't exist before putting the actual file in it.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try to change it to absolute path (C:\absolutepath\character.json) because when you run the project from Eclipse you are inside the "right contest" so the program find your relative path.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: If i were you i would be more worried about compiling code that has no error handling... First things first and all that. A single log statement would have already told you what the error was by now.

Comment: @Tylmomendog that is why you have debug logs. You can't convince me that proper logging wouldn't enable you to fix this, it's not magic after all. Implement proper logging and error handling and your life will be much easier.

Comment: @Tylmomendog this is where debug logs would help, they act as checkpoints for your code, you know where your code got to before it flopped. The bottom line is, you've compiled code that you cannot debug. I'm sure you appreciate why that's making your life harder right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since outside Eclipse neither the bin nor the file itself haven't been created yet, you have to create it, at first and if there was a file before, since we want to overwrite it, we use the delete method before creating it. So the whole changes are written here:

```
public void saveCharacterInfo() {

    JSONObject obj = JSONUtils.getJSONObjectFromFile("/character.json");
    obj.put("day", c.getDay());
    obj.put("name", c.getCharName());
    obj.put("hp", c.getCharHp());
    obj.put("maxHp", c.getCharHpMax());
    obj.put("armor", c.getCharArmor());
    obj.put("speed", c.getCharSpeed());
    obj.put("strength", c.getCharStrength());
    obj.put("money", c.getCharMoney());
    obj.put("food", c.getCharFood());
    obj.put("maxFood", c.getCharMaxFood());
    obj.put("morale", c.getCharMorale());
    obj.put("bait", c.getCharBait());

    try {

        URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("/character.json");
        File file = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write(obj.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I tested it and the way to make the jar to create new folders is to execute it from the windows command console with:

```
java -jar jarName.jar
```

Or to create a bat file on the same folder.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work, i still have the same problem. Works inside eclipse, not after export.

Comment: I executed that same code from the console and it created the bin folder with the json file inside the folder you have the jar in.

Comment: I think I just figured it out, please tell me if I'm wrong, but since the .json file inside the .jar file is "read only" i can't write to it. (Didn't know it was read only).

Comment: Yes you can't actually modify the inside files from a .jar since they are read-only, if you want some data to be saved I recommend you using the Temp folder.